# If functions producing different values for likert scale responses

Tags: excel, excel-formula, likert

So I am looking to write a function code that will assign different values to different answers.
I.E if someone responds with a "strongly agree" I need a 4 value assigned but if they responded "agree somewhat" I need a 3 assigned.

I imagine this uses a combo of IF, OR and AND functions but I am unsure

Answer (score 2):

Create a lookup table *(on right in photo)* to store your mappings. Then use a `VLOOKUP` to convert your string input to a score output. See photo below with setup & usecase

[image]